# No internet access on Android TV

Tags: android, cordova, android-tv

I'm trying to make a HTML5 app for Android TV platform with Cordova and debug it through AVD. When I install my app on a phone emulator, the network access is working but when I use a TV emulator (Android TV (720p) API 28), any request gives a network error. Another apps (not mine) have internet access and work properly.

UPD: selected API 22 instead of 28 and it started to work, but it's too old and I don't know if my app will work on more recent TVs. So I still need to know how to fix it.

My config.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="..." version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>My app</name>
    <description>A Quasar Framework app</description>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1" />
    <allow-navigation href="*" />
    <allow-intent href="*" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    </platform>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-android-tv" spec="^1.0.3" />
    <engine name="android" spec="^8.1.0" />
</widget>
```

Answer (score 0):

Cleartext traffic support became disabled by default with API level 28. You may be having a problem with that. I have no experience in Cordova but in android you can enable it in your manifest file.

In the manifest file, inside the application tag you can add `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` to enable it.

```
<manifest>
    <application
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        >
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Hope you can apply this in Cordova. Not 100% sure if this is the problem but it is worth giving a try.